# Swift, How to make user-input form data observable to a viewModel for use in viewModel's functions?

Tags: swift, xcode, forms, mvvm, viewmodel

Using Swift programatically (no storyboard), I have a View ("ProfileFormView") which contains a 'Form {}' with multiple pickers and datePickers.  I need my ViewModel ("EarningsViewModel") to observe and utilize the information the user selected in the ProfileFormView Form{}.  How do I make the form's user-inputs observable to my viewModel?

View code:

```
struct ProfileFormView: View {

@State private var birthdate = Date()
@State private var newHireDate = Date()
@State private var chosenRetireAge = 65
let retirementAges = 60...65
@State private var chosenHours = 76
let hoursFlown = 68...95
@State private var chosenAircraft = "B717"
let currentAircraft = ["B717","B737","B757","B767-4","A220","A320","A330","A350"]
@State private var chosenSeat = "Captain"
let twoSeats = ["First Officer", "Captain"]
@State private var chosenYearUpgrade = 10
let yearToUpgrade = 2...30
@State private var chosenYearUpgrade2 = 10
let yearToUpgrade2 = 2...30
@State private var chosenAircraft2 = "A330"
let secondAircraft = ["B717","B737","B757","B767-4","A220","A320","A330","A350"]
@State var upgraded: Bool
@State var upgraded2: Bool
@State var planningToUpgrade: Bool
@State var planningToUpgrade2: Bool
@State var planningToSwitch: Bool

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("Personal Information")) {...
```

ViewModel code:

```
class EarningsViewModel: ObservableObject {

func calcYearsRemaining(retireAge: Int, birthday: String) -> Int {
let dateFormater = DateFormatter()
dateFormater.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
let birthdayDate = dateFormater.date(from: birthday)
let calendar: NSCalendar! = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: .gregorian)
let now = Date()
let calcAge = calendar.components(.year, from: birthdayDate!, to: now, options: [])
let age = calcAge.year
let yearsRemaining = retireAge - age!
return yearsRemaining
 ....}
```

In order to pull data from a Model I make the Model an ObservableObject.  Xcode tells me it's not permissible to make my View (FormProfileView) an ObservableObject.  The user selects their birthdate, the date they starting working for the company, the age they plan to retire, etc... and I need to use that data in functions in my "EarningsViewModel"

Thank you for your help!

[image of form][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyPf9.png

Comment: Check out some SwiftUI tutorials (like Apple's or Hacking with Swift's). You'll see examples of creating an `ObservableObject`, and using the `@StateObject` and `@ObservableObject` property wrappers to hook it up to your views.

Comment: @jnpdx. I am intimately familiar with developer.apple tutorials, Hacking with Swift's, CodingWithChris, Sean Allen, and many others.  You are right, they do teach ObservableObjects, StateObjects, etc but not in the way I explained in my question.  Here is the issue: Xcode tells me Views cannot be ObservableObjects.  Apple, Paul Hudson and all the others teach how to make Models and ViewModels into ObservableObjects... but not Views.  If you know of a specific tutorial that teaches how to make Views into ObservableObjects please let me know.

Comment: Views, by definition, are value types. ObservableObjects, by definition, are reference types. There is not a way to make a View into an ObservableObject

Comment: @jnpdx Thanks, that makes sense.  So back to my question: if my view has a Form which takes user input, how do I program my View (with the Form) to communicate its user-form-inputs to my ViewModel or to another View?

Comment: If you need to communicate to another view, the state needs to be owned by a common ancestor. In terms of getting the form to communicate with a StateObject, that’s why I suggested the tutorials — perhaps you could clarify what the issue is, because this seems like a basic SwiftUI concept, but given that you said you’re already quite familiar with the tutorials, I’m guessing there’s a detail about what makes this different that I’m missing.

Comment: @jnpdx. The common ancestor tip may be helpful for sharing data between views.  I'll give that a try.  Regarding my problem of getting information from a Form (in a View) to a ViewModel, I have not seen this in any tutorial.  To be specific, what the tutorials teach is to make your ViewModel an ObservableObject and use StateObject in your View in order for viewmodel information to be accessed by the view.  I see a "oneway street" here.  I need this to be a two-way street: data from the Form changing variables in a viewmodel.  (default age was 30, but the user Form input is an age of "35")

Comment: By having a `@Published` property on your view model, you can have a two-way binding.